# How to change the background-color of an input field based on the val of that input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-color, inline-styles

I have an input field with a hex color value:

```
<input class="color" value="#ff0000" /> // ff0000 is red
```

How can i read the val from this field and set the value as background-color for that field?
So i want to achieve:

```
<input class="color" style="background-color: #ff0000;" value="#ff0000" />
```

Comment: As you've tagged jQuery, research https://api.jquery.com/on and https://api.jquery.com/css. If you've made an attempt yourself to achieve this, please add the code to the question so we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var bgcolor = $('.color').val(); // create var which reads the value from input with class .color
   $('.color').css( "background-color", bgcolor ); // now set css rule to the same .color class with that var
});
```